# Python function interface for Haskell - Module not found/DecodeException - pyfi

Tags: python, haskell

I have just tried [pyfi](https://github.com/Russell91/pyfi) and it gives me "Module not found" error. Any ideas what could be wrong ?

[image]

Also, related question, why does the example below from the github page not work ?

Why is 4 not JSON serializable ? Is this a bug in pyfi ?

[image]

Update (trying to debug):

[image]

After setting export PYTHONPATH=.

[image]

Comment: `4` is not serializable as JSON because the top level construct has to be a list or an object.  You could have `{"value": 4}` or `[4]`, but not `4`.  This is my guess anyway.  I'm not familiar with `pyfi`, but you could try a simpler import than a `from ... import ... as ...` to see if you can at least get the function itself.

Comment: Thanks ! I have a look !

Comment: Btw, `square` just works fine. What do you mean by function itself ? The function seems to be working, that is where the `4` is coming from.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: The arguments against screenshots are pretty poor. SOF should make screenshots searchable like Evernote does instead of limiting users.

Comment: That would solve both the screenreader and searchability problem...